# How do you find a document by its ID using version 9 of the Firebase JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The [new version 9 of the Firebase JS SDK has arrived](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/08/the-new-firebase-js-sdk-now-ga.html) with a more modular approach, and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

I want to find and read a document from Firestore by its ID. In version 8, you could do:

```
await db.collection('users').doc(id).get();
```

Version 9 seems to have a function called ["doc"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#doc), and one called ["getDoc"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#getdoc), that could sound like the new equivalent, but I don't understand how to use them in practice. Has someone else played around with these yet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) has a complete code snippet explaining how to fetch a single document with given ID:

```js
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "users", id);
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

The `doc()` method is used to get a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) and `getDoc()` is used to fetch the document from given reference.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I couldn't find that page in their documentation, but that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @TheWormple here is the [link to Firestore's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore)