# How to access a firestore doc that has been created for my users on account creation so they can update/add user information

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a cloud function that successfully creates a document in a collection called 'users', this doc generates an auto ID and saves their email upon them creating an account. The problem I'm having is accessing this document so the user can submit a form in the UI and update/add information such as; username, first name, profile pic, birthday, etc...

My pop-out form in the UI is working correctly ie it closes when I press submit button, but the data I input is being written into the localhost URL. - I'm thinking this is because it is not connecting to firestore in some way.

Code in auth.js file
**All imports**

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { db, auth } from "./firebase";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
```

**In order of sequence**

```
// Initiate firebase auth
export function initFirebaseAuth() {
    // Listen to auth state changes.
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, authStateObserver);
};

// some DOM hide element functions

// Triggers when the auth state change for instance when the user signs-in or signs-out.
function authStateObserver(user) {
    if (user !== null) {
        const displayName = user.displayName;
        const email = user.email;
        console.log(displayName, email + ' is logged in')

        // User is signed in! Show on Profile info
        displayUser.appendChild(displayUserEmail);
        displayUserEmail.textContent = `Logged in as: ${user.email}`;

        // Get the signed-in user's profile pic and name.
        var profilePicUrl = getProfilePicUrl();
        var userName = getUserName();

        // Set the user's profile pic and name.
        userPicElement.style.backgroundImage =
            'url(' + addSizeToGoogleProfilePic(profilePicUrl) + ')';
        userNameElement.textContent = userName;

        // Show user's profile and sign-out button.
        // Hide sign-in button.
        userIsLoggedIn();

        // show post form
        shareContent.removeAttribute('hidden');

        // We save the Firebase Messaging Device token and enable notifications.
        // saveMessagingDeviceToken();
    } else {
        // User is signed out!
        console.log('no user is logged in ');
        // Hide user's profile and sign-out button.
        // Show sign-in button.
        noUserLoggedIn();

        // hide post form
        shareContent.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
    }
    // return user, displayName, email, photoURL, emailVerified, uid;
};


// Returns the signed-in user's profile Pic URL.
export function getProfilePicUrl() {
    return auth.currentUser.photoURL || '/Assets/Images/profile_placeholder.png';
};

// Returns the signed-in user's display name.
function getUserName() {
    return '@' + auth.currentUser.displayName || 'Create Username';
};
```

User **Signup Form**

```
// create Account
if (signUpForm) {
    signUpForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        //get user info
        const email = signUpForm['signupEmail'].value;
        const password = signUpForm['signupPassword'].value;

        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((cred) => {
            // hide signup form and show profile edit form - reset signup form
            hideSignUpModal();
            profileModal.classList.remove('hidden');

            // reset form
            signUpForm.reset();
            document.getElementById("signUpErr").innerHTML = "";
            //return user 
            console.log(user);
            console.table(cred);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            document.getElementById("signUpErr").innerHTML = err.message;
        })
    })
}
```

**login form**

```
// login form
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const email = loginForm['loginUsername'].value;
    const password = loginForm['loginPassword'].value;

    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(() => {
        // hide login form
        hideLoginModal();

        // reset form
        loginForm.reset();
        // ...
        document.getElementById("loginErr").innerHTML = "";
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        document.getElementById("loginErr").innerHTML = err.message;
    });
});

const logout = document.querySelector('#logout');
if (logout) {
    logout.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (!e.target.closest('.transBtn')) return;
        auth.signOut().then(() => {
            console.log('user signed out')
        });
    });

};
```

**profile edit form**

```
// some DOM element hide/show code

// checking for user ID
const currentUserId = auth.currentUser.uid;
console.log(currentUserId);

// edit profile
editProfileButton.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return setDoc(doc(db, 'users', cred.user.uid), {
        photoURL: newProfilePicURL(),
        displayName: userNameInputElement.value,
        firstName: firstNameInputElement.value,
        lastName: lastNameInputElement.value,
        birthday: birthdayInputElement.value
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`updated ${displayName}'s user info`);
        alert('Your profile information has been saved!');
        // Profile updated!
        profileModal.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
        // ...
    }).catch((error) => {
        // An error occurred
        console.error('Error Firebase Database', error.message);
        // ...
    })
})

initFirebaseAuth();
hideLoginModal();
hideSignUpModal();
hideProfileModal();
```

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69012256/13130697) on how to get a single document by ID?

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj thanks for the response. I have read much of the documentation the problem is making sense of it all and knowing what is the right thing to apply for which part. This helps a lot thank you! The answer you linked may help me reverse engineer, however, how do I get the document that is linked to my current signed-in user?

Comment: The document ID is current user's UID? You can get it anytime by `auth.currentUser.uid`

Comment: Great thanks! So this would work however I'm getting a property of null (reading 'uid'), which may be the root of my problem because I do have an account signed into my app.

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant code (the complete function)? It seems you are querying document directly on page load without waiting for auth state to load

Comment: Interesting, this may be it. Would this mean changing the function to an async await? Thanks for your help, this has been a week-long problem for me.

Comment: No, you should use `onAuthStateChanged()` observer. Unsure why are you logging user ID just below a login function.. where are you attempting to get the doc by ID? It'll be best to share that part

Comment: Okay, I have not shared the code in the sequence above I will edit it to show the code.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have updated the question to the full order of main functions.

Comment: As suggested by *Dharmaraj*, can you try using [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) instead of `authStateObserver()`? And have a look at this [Article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0#:~:text=Use%20an%20auth%20state%20observer%20(AKA%20auth%20state%20listener))

Comment: Thanks @RoopaM, I have checked out the article once again it is helpful to understand. My auth state when signed in is readable within the ```initFirebaseAuth()``` function at the top of my document, but not anywhere else. Would the solution be to call my ```editProfileButton``` within the authstateObserver if = true?

Comment: Yes, Can you try to call `editProfileButton` within the `authstateObserver` ? and let me know if you are still facing same problem?