# Firebase FireStore : How to get document snapshot after adding document with addDoc()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So in firebase 8 , it is possible to do

```
const songRef = await songCollection.add(song);
```

and then

```
const screenShot = await songRef.get()
```

However firebase 9 uses the addDoc() method to create a document , so I can add document like

```
const songRef = await addDoc(songsCollection, song);
```

but geting  songRef.get() is not a function . So how do I get the document snapshot I just created?

Comment: This might be useful [How do you find a document by its ID using version 9 of the Firebase JS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69012256/13130697)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`songRef` should contain an `id`, which you can use to get the document with like so: `getDoc(songRef.id)`

Comment: [`getDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#getdoc) takes a `DocumentReference` as argument. So I believe you don't need to use the id when calling it. You can simply call `getDoc(songRef)`.